# Find or describe all associative algebras possessing only inner derivations.

Tags: associativity

From cohomology theory we know that separables algebras $A$ possess only inner derivations. In fact, they possess only inner Derivation into every $A$-bimodule $M$ which characterize separable algebras.

For example, the Algebra of upper triangular matrices over a field or the Solomon-Algebra in characteristic Zero possess only inner derivations.

My question is to describe those associative algebras -- maybe also finite-dimensional -- which possess only inner derivations.

Comment: All $R$-separable algebras belong to this class, see [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71869/an-r-algebra-a-is-r-separable-if-and-only-if-all-derivations-are-inner).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Dietrich. Do you some more examples possessing only inner derivations besides the mentioned ones?

Comment: see also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308957/find-or-describe-all-associative-algebras-possessing-only-inner-derivations

Comment: I click on the link and it doesn exists aenynore

Comment: yes the question was deleted.

Comment: I think we can close the question.